# how to run my local selenium test script in AWS without using jenkins

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, selenium

How to run my local selenium test script in AWS without using jenkins?

I just want to deploy my test case.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this using docker container.
You must need to install java in your machine

Then you need to setup selenium docker container.

Install docker in your ec2 machine

Then run the following command

```
sudo docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.141.59-mercury &&
sudo docker run -d -P -p 5900:5900 --link selenium-hub:hub -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/node-chrome-debug:3.141.59-mercury
```

**Reference :** https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
Now you can view selenium grid in your `ip:4444` port

Now you need to initialize chrome driver.

```
WebDriver driver;
String nodeUrl;
nodeUrl =  "http://172.17.0.3:5555/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.getCurrent());
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl), capabilities);
```

If your project is maven project then you can run project simply `mvn test`

**maven project references** https://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html

Now you can run your test case inside aws machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can spin up ec2 instance and can configured your selenium job in
   to it.
2. You can use AWS codebuild.
3. AWS LAMBDA is also there . [link](https://medium.com/@Moatazeldebsy/ui-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-and-chrome-inside-aws-lambda-77a17ec64862) for your reference.